# Kotlin get runtime class from generic implementation

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to build a register component that takes in a list of QueryHandlers in my application.
Below you can see the queryHandler and Query definition. They both implement an interface with generics.

```
class MyQueryHandler(): QueryHandler<MyQuery, MyReturnType>

class MyQuery(val query: String) : Query<MyReturnType>
```

Now, I have a component in Spring that is using BeanPostProcessor to catch the Bus bean definition and call to it the function `registerQueryHandler` for each of the query handler he gets in the list.
`registerQueryHandler` signature is

```
fun <Q : Query<V>, V> registerQueryHandler(aClass: Class<Q>, queryHandler: QueryHandler<Q, V>)
```

so it takes the query handler and the class resulting from the query execution.

Below is the pseudocode of my BeanPostProcessor

```
class SimpleQueryBusPostProcessor(
    private val queryHandlers: List<QueryHandler<Q<V>, V>>,
    private val beanNameSelector: String
) : BeanPostProcessor {

    override fun postProcessAfterInitialization(bean: Any, beanName: String): Any? {
        if (beanName == beanNameSelector && bean is SimpleMessageBus) {
            queryHandlers.forEach {
                bean.registerQueryHandler(#runtimeClassForQ<V>onIt, it)
            }
        }
        return bean
    }
}
```

My problem is on "#runtimeClassForQonIt" I would like to know at runtime, given a specific QueryHandler, which concrete implementation of the Query it is implementing to register it into the Bus.
Any idea on how can I achieve this?

---

I've tried with some inline function to get it using reified like below, but I only get back the interface that T implements (Query) instead of the concrete class

```
private inline fun <reified T: Q<P>, P> getClazz(handler: QueryHandler<T, P>) : Class<T> {
        return T::class.java
    }
```

Comment: Your QueryHandler class will have to have a Class or KClass property in its constructor because otherwise, there is no way to retrieve the class at runtime.

Comment: yeah I thought about having a getHandledQuery method in the handler to handle that, but I was wondering whether I could do something smarter